# Creating a Bar Graph in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, graph

I want to ask anyone who knows how to create a bar graph in VS2010 C# Windows Forms??

I already searched the web on how to do it but it gives me examples of ASP.NET C#.

What I need to graph are my queries pertaining to the grades of my students..

The table below for example are the data from my database..

```
Name    Grade 

Kevin   85
James   80
Hyde    90
Manu    85
```

Thanks in advance..
I'm using VS2010 C# and Sql Server 2005 for my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of readymade controls you can find on the web (ie: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14422), or you can write one your own, maybe starting from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20146/Write-Your-Own-Bar-Chart-Winforms-User-Control

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MS Chart control, just drag it from your toolbox on to a form and associate it with data you have.

Have a look here: [MS CHart Example (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET)